# Properly inputting a float into a struct well also printing other prompts (difference between scanf and fgets)?

Tags: c, scanf, prompt, fgets

So I'm trying to prompt the user to enter a float price, and two separate char strings for my uni class which then passes by value into another function.
I have tried using `scanf` to enter this float into a `newRental.price` variable directly. The issue with this is that the program then terminates without ever printing the other two prompts, if I were to use this option, how do I account for the `\n` (assuming that's what it is) left in the buffer by `scanf` so that the other two prompts will appear and properly format?

The other option I've tried is to use fgets into a `char getPrice[100]`
and then assign my `newRental.price = getPrice[100]` (saw this on another answer elsewhere on this site), which after passing into the next function and printing produces garbage nonsense.

What is the optimal way to input a float into a struct well also having it also printing all 3 prompts so I can have it print properly in the addRecord function?

I've debated just portraying and inputting the float as a char[] (as in char price[100] in the struct declaration) but this mystery is driving me crazy.

This screenshot is what happens if use fgets to input a number into a char[] and then assign it to a float.

[image: example output of what happens after using fgets/assigning char to float]

```
void addRecord(struct movieRental);

struct movieRental {
  float price;
  char title[100];
  char director[100];
};

int main() {
  struct movieRental newRental;

  while (1) {                                                       //input menu
    printf("MENU\n");
    printf("=====\n");
    printf("1. Add record \n");
    printf("2. Delete record \n");
    printf("3. Print all records \n");
    printf("4. Print number of records \n");
    printf("5. Print size of database \n");
    printf("6. Print number of accesses to database \n");
    printf("7. Exit\n");
    printf("Enter selection :");
    int sel;
    scanf("%d", &sel);
    switch (sel) {
      case 1:
        fgetc(stdin);              //input as a char and then convert to a float
                                   //after passing into addRecord produces garbage
        printf("Please type in a price: ");
        char getPrice[100];
        fgets(getPrice, 100, stdin);
        getPrice[strlen(getPrice - 1)] = 0;
        newRental.price = getPrice[100];
        //memcpy(newRental.price, getPrice, sizeof(getPrice));
        //scanf("%f", newRental.price);                           //using this option promptly terminates the program

        char getTitle[100];
        printf("Please type in a movie: ");
        fgets(getTitle, 100, stdin);
        getTitle[strlen(getTitle) - 1] = 0;
        memcpy(newRental.title, getTitle, sizeof(getTitle));

        char getDirector[100];
        printf("Please type in a director: ");
        fgets(getDirector, 100, stdin);
        getDirector[strlen(getDirector - 1)] = 0;
        memcpy(newRental.director, getDirector, sizeof(getDirector));

        addRecord(newRental);
        break;
      case 7: //theirs other cases to be put here but for formatting im gonna keep it short
        exit(0);
    }
  }
}

void addRecord(struct movieRental newRental) {
  fprintf(stderr, "The value of add.price is %f\n", newRental.price);
  fprintf(stderr, "The value of add.title is %s\n", newRental.title);
  fprintf(stderr, "The value of add.director is %s\n", newRental.director);

}
```

Comment: Typo:  `strlen(getPrice-1)` --> `strlen(getPrice)-1`.  Same with `getDirector`

Comment: Thank you. that fixed getDirector not printing, but get price is still just printing "83.00000"

Comment: This is a handy cheat sheet for printf format modifiers: https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet/ I'd say you'd need `%.2f`

Comment: You have `newRental.price = getPrice[100];` — which is accessing beyond the last element of the array and is not converting the string.  You need `newRental.price = strtod(getPrice, NULL);` or thereabouts (there are numerous alternatives ways of converting a string to a floating point number, but what you tried is not one of them).

Answer (score 0):

> What is the optimal way to input a float into a struct well also having it also printing all 3 prompts so I can have it print properly in the `addRecord` function?

Reading 3 lines with 3 `fgets()` is a good start.

I'd use a common large buffer and use it for each read and then assess the line of input for correctness.

If all 3 correct, then `addRecord(newRental)`.

---

To convert a *line* of user input into a `float`:

1. Read in line of input text into a *string*.

   ```
    // fgets(getPrice, 100, stdin);  This is OP's code
    if (fgets(getPrice, sizeof getPrice, stdin) == NULL) Handle_NoInput(); // Recommendation
   ```

Convert string to `float`

```
    // getPrice[strlen(getPrice-1)]=0;  // UB: Attempt to access outside `getPrice[]`.
    // newRental.price = getPrice[100]; // UB: attempt to access outside `getPrice[]`.

    // Error checking omitted for brevity, but possible (not shown)
    newRental.price = strtof(getPrice, NULL); 
    // or
    newRental.price = atof(getPrice); // No error checking possible
    // or 
    // A little error checking here
    if (sscanf(getPrice, "%f", &newRental.price) == 1) Success();
```

---

`getTitle[strlen(getTitle)-1]= 0;` is an incorrect attempt to lop off trailing `'\n'`.  Use:

```
getTitle[strcspn(getTitle, "\n")] = '\0';
```

---

`void addRecord(struct movieRental);` should come *after* `struct movieRental` declaration.

---

Perhaps other problems too.